# Uniform convergence of functions with values in a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be any family of functions
with value in a Hilbert space $\mathcal H\,$.
Suppose that, for all $t\in \mathbb R\,$, $f_n(t)$ converges weakly in $\mathcal H$ to a limit $f(t)$.
Then, it is well--known that if $\|f_n(t)\|_{\mathcal H}\to \|f(t)\|_{\mathcal H}\,,$ for all $t\,,$ then we have
$$
f_n(t)\to f(t) \text { in } \mathcal H\,\qquad \text{ as } n\to \infty\,\qquad \forall t.
$$
Now, suppose that $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ in $\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R;\mathcal H)\,,$ where $\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R;\mathcal H)$ denotes the space of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ with value in $\mathcal H$ . Is there any analog of the above theorem that ensures
$$
 \sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\|f_n(t)-f(t)\|_{\mathcal H}\to 0 \quad \text{ as } n\to \infty\,.
$$

Comment: What topology are you placing on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{H})$?

Comment: Normed vector space with norm : $\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\|f(t)\|_{\mathcal H}$ .

Comment: There is no reason that that quantity is finite for an arbitrary continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{H}$ (even in the case where $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{R}$). It is not a norm on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{H})$.

Comment: I should probably consider the space of bounded continuous functions $f:R\to \mathcal H$. (I will edit the question)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. The main problem is that your assumptions do not have anything to do with the variable $t$.

For a counterexample consider $\mathcal H=\mathbb R$ and
$f_n(t)$ be the function that is zero everywhere except for the interval $(1-1/n,1+1/n)$, where it has a bump such that
$$\max_{(1-1/n,1+1/n)}f_n(t)=1.$$
You can prove by hand that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $f_n(t)\rightarrow 0$, so you have both weak and strong convergence of the sequence $\{f_n(t)\}$ to $0$, and $0\in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{H})$, however $\sup || f_n(t)-0 ||$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: But the $f_n$ in your example are not continuous in time !

Comment: You can choose them to be continuous (taking small triangles for example)

Comment: Actually, my question was: What are the conditions that we need to add, to expect having a strong uniform convergence in $\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R, \mathcal H)$ with the topology induced by $\sup_{t\in \mathbb R}\|f(t)\|_{\mathcal H}$?

Comment: I think that a generalized Ascoli's theorem could be an answer. For instance, the result of Krukowski-Przeradzki "Compactness result and its applications in integral
equations" where they proved a generalized version of Ascoli's theorem in $\mathcal C_b(X,Y)$ with $X$ is a $\sigma$-locally compact Hausdorff space and $Y$ is a metric space.